# Adding entities to collection removes the oldest entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following two (simplified) classes. A fleet is basically a collection of vehicles.

```
public class Fleet : IFleet
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    public IVehicle VehicleTemplate { get; set; }

    public Fleet(IVehicle vehicleTemplate, int quantity)
    {
        VehicleTemplate = vehicleTemplate;
        Vehicles = new List<IVehicle>();
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            var vehicle = new Vehicle(vehicleTemplate);
            Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
            vehicle.Fleet = this;
        }
    }
}

public class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public IFleet Fleet { get; set; }

    public int FleetID { get; set; }
}
```

I can create Fleets containing multiple vehicles just fine like this:

```
var fleet = new Fleet(vehicleTemplate, quantity);
fleetRepository.Add(fleet);
vehicleRepository.AddRange(fleet.Vehicles);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, whenever I add a vehicle to an existing fleet like in the following example, Entity Framework deletes the oldest vehicle from the database. (It actually executes *DELETE FROM [Vehicles]
WHERE [ID] = @p18;* where @p18 is always the ID of the oldest vehicle in the fleet.)

```
var fleet = fleetRepository.Get(fleetID);
var newVehicle = new Vehicle(fleet.VehicleTemplate);
newVehicle.Fleet = fleet;
fleet.Vehicles.Add(newVehicle);
vehicleRepository.Add(newVehicle);
fleetRepository.Update(fleet);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Further testing reveals that only a single record is deleted every time, even when multiple vehicles are added to the fleet at once like in the following code example. It is always the oldest record.

```
var fleet = fleetRepository.Get(fleetID);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    var newVehicle = new Vehicle(fleet.VehicleTemplate);
    newVehicle.Fleet = fleet;
    fleet.Vehicles.Add(newVehicle);
    vehicleRepository.Add(newVehicle);
}
fleetRepository.Update(fleet);
context.SaveChanges();
```

What is happening here and what can I do so that no vehicle is lost?

Edit: The methods for the repositories that are called look like this:

```
public class Repository<IEntity, TEntity, TIdentifier> : IRepository<IEntity, TIdentifier> where IEntity : class where TEntity : class, IEntity where TIdentifier : IEquatable<TIdentifier>
{
    protected readonly DbContext context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Add(IEntity entity)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Add((TEntity)entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<IEntity> entities)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities.Cast<TEntity>());
    }

    public void Update(IEntity entity)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Update((TEntity)entity);
    }
}

public class VehicleRepository : Repository<IVehicle, Vehicle, Guid>, IVehicleRepository
{
    public VehicleRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class FleetRepository :  Repository<IFleet, Fleet, int>, IFleetRepository
{
    public FleetRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public IFleet Get(int id)
    {
        IQueryable<IFleet> query = context.Set<Fleet>();
        query = query.Include(f => f.Vehicles);
        fleet = query.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);
        return fleet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your repository code.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I have added the code.

Comment: What happens inside the constructor? `new Vehicle(fleet.VehicleTemplate);`

Comment: There are implementation (`query.Include(f => f.Vehicles);` - not using the return value) and model - interfaces in navigation like properties - not sure how you mapped the relationships and how this model works at all.

Comment: @IvanStoev I must have deleted the assignment when I formatted the code here. It's `query = query.Include(f => f.Vehicles);`.
The interfaces are mapping is just `modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().HasOne(v => (Fleet)v.Fleet).WithMany(nameof(Fleet.Vehicles));`

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of redundant EF commands. You can just do;

```
var fleet = fleetRepository.Get(fleetID);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
    var newVehicle = new Vehicle(fleet.VehicleTemplate);
    newVehicle.FleetID = fleet.ID;
    vehicleRepository.Add(newVehicle);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed that. The problem remains, however.

Comment: @Kisar I updated the code, instead of assigning the navigation property `Vehicle.Fleet`, we're going to assign `Vehicle.FleetID`